# R - converting data frame to matrix, get different results when using head()

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a data frame that has around 78,000 rows and looks like this:

```
EmailAddress    Column1 Column2 Column3
abc1@gmail.com     1       0       0
abc2@gmail.com     0       0       0
abc3@gmail.com     1       1       0
abc4@gmail.com     1       1       0
```

I want to run a kmeans clustering on it using `kcca()` function.
I want to convert this data frame into a matrix but I want to keep column EmailAddress so that I can link the output to the original data.
I ran the `as.matrix()` function as follows and I seems to get different results when I run `str()` command.

first time Im running it on the whole data frame, as you can see I get the first element, which should be column names as NULL and the second element, which should be the data 1 or 0, as EmailAddresses.

second time I run it, Im using `head()` function, asking for the top 100,000 and now I get the matrix that Im looking for.

why is this the case?

```
> y <- as.matrix(clicked_data[,1:24])
> str(y)
 chr [1:78748, 1:24] "abc1@gmail.com" "abc2@gmail.com" "abc3@msn.com" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:24] "EmailAddress" "Column1" "column2" "Column3" ...

> y <- as.matrix(head(clicked_data[,1:24],100000))
> str(y)
 chr [1:10000, 1:24] "abc1@gmail.com" "abc2@gmail.com" "abc3@msn.com" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:78748] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:24] "EmailAddress" "Column1" "column2" "Column3" ...
```

Comment: the data isn't different, just the `dimnames` (ignoring the difference in number of rows, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case `NULL` is because rows of the matrix is not named. On the other hand, `head()` seems to put row names so that it appears in `dimnames`.

The output clarifies it.

```
df <- read.table(head = T, text = "EmailAddress    Column1 Column2 Column3
abc1@gmail.com     1       0       0
abc2@gmail.com     0       0       0
abc3@gmail.com     1       1       0
abc4@gmail.com     1       1       0")

mat <- as.matrix(df)
#         EmailAddress     Column1 Column2 Column3
#[1,] "abc1@gmail.com" "1"     "0"     "0"    
#[2,] "abc2@gmail.com" "0"     "0"     "0"    
#[3,] "abc3@gmail.com" "1"     "1"     "0"    
#[4,] "abc4@gmail.com" "1"     "1"     "0"  
mat1 <- as.matrix(head(df, 2))
#      EmailAddress     Column1 Column2 Column3
#1 "abc1@gmail.com" "1"     "0"     "0"    
#2 "abc2@gmail.com" "0"     "0"     "0"
```